# What is characsteric property of a algebraic equation showing a closed curve?

Tags: geometry

So, if we have an equation of $x^2 +y^2 =1$,  then we can find it shapes a closed circle curve. My question is what is the generally property of the equation of form:
$$ F(x,y) = 0$$

Comment: What you say about conics should be stated with much more care because there are large classes of exceptions. A few examples of exceptions include $xy=0$, and $y=x^2$, and $x^2-y^2=c$.

Comment: Edited that out

Comment: It's an important topic in mathematics. To begin see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve

Comment: One method would be to convert to projective coordinates via the substitutions $x=X/Z$ and $y=Y/Z$, then intersect with the line at infinity $Z=0$, and see if there are any real roots.